# Convert from 2018-10-23T06:01:10.806Z to 10-May-2018 and a seperate string for time

Tags: ios, swift, date, time, converters

have to extract a separate date and time from the same string i.e)2018-10-23T06:01:10.806Z, the date must be in the format of 10-May-2018 and the time must be in 12 hours format i.e) 08:00 PM

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: No one will write code for you. Please elaborate which kind of error are you facing? What have you done to achieve your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 func formatDateString(dateString: String) -> Date? {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"

    return dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
}
```

You get the `Date` object, do whatever you can do whatever you wanted using that.